# View website like a search engine

Tags: seo

I once found a site where you can enter a web address and it returns a view of the website with the elements a search engine would 'see' but in the same layout as the original website. 
I found these tools: SEO-browser.com and MozBar but they don't show the site in the same layout.

So for example adverts loaded by Javascript after page load would not appear in the search engine view but it would still show a similar layout to the normal website view. I realise a search engine doesn't see the site this way and SEO-browser and Mozbar are probably more correct but this tool helps me understand what's going on better.

I'm pretty sure the site I'm trying to find was mentioned on SEOMoz or another reputable site but I cant for the life of me find it. Any suggestions or similar tools would be helpful?

Comment: Tools > View source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by turning JavaScript off in your browser:

Chrome:

1. Click on the settings icon on the top right of chrome.
2. Click settings
3. click 'Show advanced settings...'
4. Click 'Content Settings' under Privacy
5. Click 'Do not allow any site to run JavaScript' radio button

FireFox

1. In Firefox for Windows, from the Tools menu, select Options.
2. If the menu bar is hidden, press Alt to make it visible.

   In Firefox for Mac OS X, from the Firefox menu, select Preferences... .
3. Click the Content tab.
4. Check or uncheck Enable JavaScript.

There are probably also extensions available for each browser that will do this at a flick of a switch.

Comment: I use this method but its not exactly what I was after but I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install Lynx text-only browser or elinks. Many of us do that to see the outline without all the decorations. If you are running Windows, you will have to check to see if either can be installed on that. I'm pretty sure Lynx can.